# Show that $x+\frac{1-e^{xy}}{x^2+y^2}$ is not continuous in $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x+\frac{1-e^{xy}}{x^2+y^2},&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0,& (x,y) = (0,0)\end{cases}$$
I must show that it is not continuous in $(0,0)$, and also in which points it is differentiable.

First I tried to verify if it's differentiable in $(0,0)$, if it is not I'll get both answers. So I easily calculated the candidate by doing $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and:
$$T(0,0)v = \lim_{t\to0}\frac{f((0,0)+tv)-f(0,0)}{t}=v_1$$
which is linear.

So, I tried to verify if $\lim_{v\to0}\frac{|r(v)|}{|v|}=0$
$$\lim_{v\to0}\frac{|r(v)|}{|v|} = \lim_{v\to0}\frac{|v_1+\frac{1-e^{v_1v_2}}{v_1^2+v_2^2}-v_1|}{|v|}=\lim_{v\to0}|\frac{1-e^{v_1v_2}}{(v_1^2+v_2^2)^{3/2}}|$$

I couldn't calculate it, and the limit to verify if it is continuous will be the same. But another thing, intuitively, as exponentials are stronger than polynomials, I'd even say that this limit exists.

Any help please?

Comment: If you find the function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ you have not proved it is not continuous at $(0,0)$. On the other hand, if you prove it is not continuous at $(0,0)$, then you have proved it is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert to polar coordinates

$x = r \cos \theta\\y=r\sin\theta\\xy = r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac {r^2}{2}\sin2\theta$

Using the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ for small $r, 1-e^{\frac {r^2}{2}\sin2\theta} \approx -\frac {r^2}{2}\sin2\theta$

As $r$ gets to be small $f(r,\theta)$ approaches $-\frac 12\sin2\theta$

In order for $\lim_\limits{r\to 0} f(r,\theta)$ to exist it must equal a single value.

Answer (score 3):

For the continuity, find the $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x,x)$, you have $1-e^{x^2}=-x^2+0(x^2)$ (use the limited development of exponantial), this implies that $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x,x)=-1/2$, since $f(0,0)=0$ $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

Look at the limit along the line $t \mapsto (0,t)$ and along the line $t \mapsto (t,t)$. As the two limits are different, the function is not continuous.

Answer (score 0):

use $$x=y=\frac{1}{n}$$ we get the Limit $$-\frac{1}{2}$$